# Oddity with migration data from questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions

Take a look at [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/91137). Apparently, it was migrated *from* ServerFault, and was originally asked by user 3d1l. However, now look at the API result: http://api.superuser.com/1.0/questions/91137 . This returns...

```
{
  "total": 1,
  "page": 1,
  "pagesize": 30,
  "questions": [
    {
      "tags": [
        "windows-vista",
        "wireless",
        "network",
        "connections"
      ],
      "answer_count": 2,
      "favorite_count": 0,
      "migrated": {
        "new_question_id": 98620,
        "to_site": {
          "name": "Server Fault",
          "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/serverfault/img/logo.png",
          "api_endpoint": "http://api.serverfault.com",
          "site_url": "http://serverfault.com",
          "description": "Q&A for system administrators and IT professionals",
          "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/serverfault/apple-touch-icon.png",
          "state": "normal",
          "styling": {
            "link_color": "#10456A",
            "tag_foreground_color": "#444444",
            "tag_background_color": "#F3F1D9"
          }
        },
        "on_date": 1262620840
      },
      "question_timeline_url": "/questions/91137/timeline",
      "question_comments_url": "/questions/91137/comments",
      "question_answers_url": "/questions/91137/answers",
      "question_id": 91137,
      "creation_date": 1262308465,
      "last_activity_date": 1279463955,
      "up_vote_count": 0,
      "down_vote_count": 0,
      "view_count": 254,
      "score": 0,
      "community_owned": false,
      "title": "How to completely remove a wireless network setup from vista?"
    }
  ]
}
```

There are two oddities here. The migration data claims it was migrated, but says "to_site" was ServerFault. Surely this should be "from_site"; similarly the new_question_id makes more sense as old_question_id.

More annoyingly, there is no data on who asked the question. Are we supposed to spin up a separate request to the origin site to request the user data? If so, it would be much more convenient to list at least the name of the question poster, as very often one just wants to display the username associated with the question.

Comment: `to_site` on the destination site is an error, as it should not be there.  It will be fixed.  The lack of a displayable name for owner-less questions is a deficiency in v1.0 of the API that has been noted elsewhere.  However, the interface is frozen so it will *not* be addressed until a subsequent version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been "fixed."

Air quotes because this reveals a deficiency in the 1.0 interface.  Namely, migrated questions are a one-way door in the 1.0 world.  You'll only see a pointer **out** of the site where it was asked, not in.

So,
http://api.serverfault.com/1.0/questions/98620 -> 
http://api.superuser.com/1.0/questions/91137
but not the other way around.